# Duplicate of richText field in Notes Document

Tags: custom-controls, lotus-notes, richtext

I have a file uploader on some of my XPages. It works so well, but there's one profound disadvantage of using it. In some cases, it creates 2 or 3 or 4 or n of duplicates of the same field inside the document. And it only happens if I try to upload a single file (or a set of files) and do the same right after it. Sometimes this happens after I delete one file and upload more. The document's fields look like this after saving. I have no idea about the reason why this happens.

[image: The result of saving]

Initially I thought that it could be because I've forgotten to put `doc_source.save();` statement in the delete button. But it didn't turned out to be the reason.

The code of the CC is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:div id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'refresh'}">
        <xp:table>
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable() && (!context.getUserAgent().isIE(6,9))
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:tr>
                <xp:td id="td1" styleClass="doc_field_select">
                    <xp:text escape="false" id="cf_add">


                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return(texticon('plus-5-icon',25,25,'Add files',false))

}]]></xp:this.value>

                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
                        disableValidators="true">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_input'}").click();]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:td>
                <xp:td styleClass="doc_field_select" id="td2">
                    <xp:text escape="false" id="cf_deleteall">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return(texticon('x-mark-4-icon',25,25,'Delete all',false))
        }]]></xp:this.value>

                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[var id='#{javascript:
getClientId(compositeData.ID+"_files_upload")}';
var tst=document.getElementById(id);
tst.value='';]]></xp:this.script>
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:actionGroup>
                                <xp:executeScript>
                                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var doc:NotesDocument=doc_source.getDocument(true);
if (doc==null)
{
return(null);
}
if (!doc.hasItem(compositeData.FieldName))
{
return(null);
}
var rit1:NotesRichTextItem=doc.getFirstItem(compositeData.FieldName);
if (rit1==null)
{
return(null);
}
try
{
var arr=rit1.getEmbeddedObjects();
}
catch(e)
{
return(null);
}

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    doc_source.removeAttachment(compositeData.FieldName, arr[i].getName());
}

return;

var doc:NotesDocument=doc_source.getDocument(true);
var rit:NotesRichTextItem=doc.getFirstItem(compositeData.FieldName);
if (rit==null)
{
return('');
}
var arr=rit.getEmbeddedObjects()
if (arr==null)
{
return('');
}
res=[]
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
var att:NotesEmbeddedObject=arr[i];
//res.push(att.getName())
arr[i].remove();
}
//doc.save()
doc=doc_source.getDocument(true);
print('has RichText');
print(doc.hasItem(compositeData.FieldName));
return;}]]></xp:this.script>
                                </xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:td>
            </xp:tr>
        </xp:table>

        <div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
            <input type="file"
                id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_input'}"
                onchange="${javascript:

      var urlToUpload = '\''+database.getHttpURL()+ database.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/') + view.getPageName() + '\'';

      var filesInput = '\'' + compositeData.ID + '_files_input' + '\'';
      var filesUpload = '\'' + compositeData.ID + '_files_upload' + '\'';
      var filesButton = '\'' +  compositeData.ID + '_files_button' + '\'';
      var filesProgress = '\'' +  compositeData.ID + '_files_progress' + '\'';

      return 'files_onchange(' + urlToUpload + ',' + filesInput + ',' + filesUpload + ',' + filesButton + ',' + filesProgress + ')';
      }"
                multiple="true" uploadOnSelect="true" name="uploadedfile" />
            <xp:fileUpload
                id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_upload'}"
                useUploadname="true">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{doc_source[compositeData.FieldName]}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:fileUpload>

            <xp:button value="Refresh"
                id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_button'}">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true"
                    refreshId="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'refresh'}">
                    <xp:this.action>

                        <xp:actionGroup>


                            <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
                            <xp:executeScript>
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if (compositeData.postUpload!=null)
{
compositeData.postUpload.getScript().invoke(facesContext, null)
}}]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:executeScript>
                        </xp:actionGroup>
                    </xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </div>

        <xp:repeat id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_repeat'}"
            rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="rowIndex">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try
{
    var doc:NotesDocument=doc_source.getDocument(true);
}
catch(e)
{
    var oss=new OsnovaSession();
}

if (doc==null)
{
return(null);
}
if (!doc.hasItem(compositeData.FieldName))
{
return(null);
}
var rit1:NotesRichTextItem=doc.getFirstItem(compositeData.FieldName);
if (rit1==null)
{
return(null);
}
try
{
var arr=rit1.getEmbeddedObjects()
}
catch(e)
{
return(null);
}
return(arr)
}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td styleClass="doc_field_select" id="td4">
                        <xp:text escape="false" id="cf_file">


                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if (rowData==null)
{
return('');
}
var siz=(rowData.getFileSize()/1024).toFixed(1);
siz=siz.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
return(texticon('download-9-icon',compositeData.IconSize,compositeData.IconSize,rowData.getName()+' ('+siz+' KB) ',false));

}]]></xp:this.value>
                            <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    if(compositeData.IconColor==null)
    {
    return('')
    }
    else
    {
    return('fill:'+compositeData.IconColor+';')
    }}]]></xp:this.style>
                        </xp:text>
                        <xp:link escape="true" text="Link"
                            id="link_test" target="_blank" style="display:none">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var oss=new OsnovaSession()
                        try
                        {
                            var db:NotesDatabase=session.getDatabase(null,null);
                            db.openByReplicaID(session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer(),compositeData.ReplicaID);
                            var doc=db.getDocumentByUNID(compositeData.DocumentUNID);
                        }
                        catch(e)
                        {
                        var doc=null;
                        }

                        if(doc==null)
                        {
                            var doc:NotesDocument=doc_source.getDocument();
                            var db=database;
                        }

                    if (doc==null)
                    {
                    return(null);
                    }

//http(s)://[yourserver]/[application.nsf]/[viewname|0]/[UNID| ViewKey]/$File/[AttachmentName]?Open

var res=oss.ServerURL()+'/';
res+=db.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/');
res+='/0/'+doc.getUniversalID()+'/$File/'+rowData.getName()+'?Open';
return(res);

//Old version
var res=oss.ServerURL()+'/'
res+=db.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/')
res+='/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/'
res+=db.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/')+'/'
res+=doc.getUniversalID()+'/$File/'+rowData.getName()+'?Open'
return(res)
}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:link>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="norefresh" disableValidators="true">
                            <!-- <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:/*
                                var res=oss.ServerURL()+'/'
                                res+=database.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/')
                                res+='/xsp/.ibmmodres/domino/OpenAttachment/'
                                res+=database.getFilePath().replace(/\\/g,'/')+'/'
                                res+=doc.getUniversalID()+'/$File/'+rowData.getName()+'?Open'
                                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(res)
                                //view.postScript("window.open('" + res + "'),'_blank'")

                                */}]]></xp:this.action> -->
                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                        var linkID = '#{javascript:getClientId("link_test")}';
                        document.getElementById(linkID).click();]]>
                            </xp:this.script>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:td>

                    <xp:td styleClass="doc_field_select" id="td3">
                        <xp:text escape="false" id="cf_del">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        return(texticon('minus-5-icon',compositeData.IconSize,compositeData.IconSize,'Delete',false));
                        }]]>
                            </xp:this.value>
                            <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        if(compositeData.IconColor==null)
                        {
                            return('');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return('fill:'+compositeData.IconColor+';');
                        }}]]></xp:this.style>
                        </xp:text>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete" disableValidators="true">
                            <xp:this.action>
                                <xp:actionGroup>
                                    <xp:executeScript>
                                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                    doc_source.removeAttachment(compositeData.FieldName, rowData.getName());
                                    doc_source.save();
                                    }]]>
                                        </xp:this.script>
                                    </xp:executeScript>

                                    <xp:executeScript>
                                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                    if (compositeData.postDelete!=null)
                                    {
                                    compositeData.postDelete.getScript().invoke(facesContext, null);
                                    }}]]></xp:this.script>
                                    </xp:executeScript>

                                </xp:actionGroup>
                            </xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:td>

                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>

        </xp:repeat>
        <span id="${javascript:compositeData.ID+'_files_progress'}">
        </span>
    </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

And the CSJS script which I use is here:

```
function files_onchange(urlToUpload, filesInput, filesUpload, filesButton, filesProgress) 
{
    var urfiles = document.getElementById(filesInput).files;
    files_upload(urlToUpload, filesInput, filesUpload, urfiles, 0, filesButton, filesProgress);
}           

function files_upload(url, filesInput, uploadID, files, counter, refreshID, filesProgress)
{
    //refreshID, uploadID not exact match
    console.log(url);
    url=""
    console.log(url)
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = null;
    var form = XSP.findForm(filesInput);
    //console.log(uploadID);
    if (!files) return;
    var numberOfFiles = files.length;
    file = files[counter];
    var max = files.length;
    if (counter >= max) return;

    formData.append(document.querySelector('[id$=' + uploadID + ']').id, file);
    formData.append("$$viewid", dojo.query("input[name='$$viewid']")[0].value);
    formData.append("$$xspsubmitid", dojo.query("input[name='$$xspsubmitid']")[0].value);
    formData.append("$$xspsubmitvalue", dojo.query("input[name='$$xspsubmitvalue']")[0].value);
    formData.append("$$xspsubmitscroll", dojo.query("input[name='$$xspsubmitscroll']")[0].value);
    formData.append(form.id, form.id);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      /* event listners */

      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) 
      {
          if (e.lengthComputable)

           {
                var percentComplete = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total);
                document.getElementById(filesProgress).innerHTML = percentComplete.toString()+'%, ( '+(counter+1).toString()+' / '+numberOfFiles.toString()+' )';
           }
              else 
              {
                document.getElementById(filesProgress).innerHTML = '...';
              } 
      }, false);


      xhr.addEventListener("load", function()
      {
          counter++; 
          if (counter >= max)
          {
              document.getElementById(filesInput).value = "";

              if (refreshID) 
              {

                  document.querySelector('[id$=' + refreshID + ']').click();

              }

          } 
        else 
              { 
                  files_upload(url, filesInput, uploadID, files, counter, refreshID, filesProgress); // сам себя, ну ебаный ты в рот блять
              }

      }, false);



     xhr.addEventListener("error", function(e) 
     {
         document.getElementById(filesProgress).innerHTML = "Error: "+e;

     }, false);

     xhr.addEventListener("abort", function()
     {
         document.getElementById(filesProgress).innerHTML = "Upload cancelled.";

     }, false);

      xhr.open("POST", url);
      xhr.send(formData);
      document.querySelector('[id$=' + uploadID + ']').value = '';
}
```

Probably this is just a Notes feature for storing RichText items? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed the way Lotus Domino stores rich text items or file attachments. [Multiple fields of the same name appear in the Properties box of a Notes document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21093942).

If your app works without other problems, there is no need to worry.